# Вопрос про RecyclerView и его построение после запроса через retrofit2

Tags: android, recyclerview, retrofit2

В общем проблема в следующем я строю список recyclerview после запроса через retrofit2, но получаю следующую проблему, список строится только после OnResume.В OnCreate пустой экран. Как только сверну приложение и запускаю все норм.Я сначала думал у меня проблемы с жизненым цикла фрагментов так как путаюсь в них, сделал в activity та же самая проблема.Мб просто то что ретрофит отрабатывает в отдельном потоке и он не успевает выполниться как  recyclerview уже строит список. Как это решить прилагаю код с активити, и тот же самый код с фрагментом. Activity

```js
public class ActiveDialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<ChatsNotAnswered> chated= new ArrayList<ChatsNotAnswered>();
    ChatsAdapter rvAdapter;
    RecyclerView rv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_active_dialog);
       // View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);
        rv = findViewById(R.id.rv1);
        requestChats();
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(rv.getContext()));
        rvAdapter = new ChatsAdapter(ActiveDialogActivity.this,chated);
        rv.setAdapter(rvAdapter);


    }

    private void init() {

        requestChats();
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(rv.getContext()));
        rvAdapter = new ChatsAdapter(ActiveDialogActivity.this,chated);
        rv.setAdapter(rvAdapter);


    }



    private void requestChats() {

        ApiUtils.getApiInterface().FetchChat(ManageAppPreferences.getToken(ActiveDialogActivity.this)).enqueue(new Callback<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    Log.d("tag1",ManageAppPreferences.getToken(ActiveDialogActivity.this) );
                    try {


                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();


                        JSONArray jsonArrayChats = new JSONArray(response.body());
                        Log.d("tag", jsonArrayChats.toString(4));
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayChats.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) jsonArrayChats.get(i);
                            ChatsNotAnswered chatsid = new ChatsNotAnswered();
                            chatsid.setchatID(json.getInt("id"));
                            chatsid.setchatName(json.getString("name"));
                            chatsid.sethash(json.getString("hash"));
                            chatsid.setlastTime(json.getString("last_time"));
                            chated.add(chatsid);
                            for (ChatsNotAnswered s : chated){
                                Log.d("tag444: ", s.toString());
                            }
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                } else {

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                // progress_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


    }




    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        init();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();


        try {


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exce unregisterReceiver", e.toString());

        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            // getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exce unregisterReceiver", e.toString());

        }
    }
}
```

Fragment

```js
public class Chats extends Fragment

{
    ArrayList<ChatsNotAnswered> chated= new ArrayList<ChatsNotAnswered>();
    ChatsAdapter rvAdapter;
    RecyclerView rv;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);
        rv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv);

        init();

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!getUserVisibleHint()) {
            return;
        }
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        requestChats();
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(rv.getContext()));
        rvAdapter = new ChatsAdapter(getContext(),chated);
        rv.setAdapter(rvAdapter);


    }



    private void requestChats() {

        ApiUtils.getApiInterface().FetchChat(ManageAppPreferences.getToken(getContext())).enqueue(new Callback<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    Log.d("tag1",ManageAppPreferences.getToken(getContext()) );
                    try {


                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();


                        JSONArray jsonArrayChats = new JSONArray(response.body());
                        Log.d("tag", jsonArrayChats.toString(4));
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayChats.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) jsonArrayChats.get(i);
                            ChatsNotAnswered chatsid = new ChatsNotAnswered();
                            chatsid.setchatID(json.getInt("id"));
                            chatsid.setchatName(json.getString("name"));
                            chatsid.sethash(json.getString("hash"));
                            chatsid.setlastTime(json.getString("last_time"));
                            chated.add(chatsid);
                            for (ChatsNotAnswered s : chated){
                                Log.d("tag444: ", s.toString());
                            }
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                } else {

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                // progress_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


    }







    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();


        try {


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exce unregisterReceiver", e.toString());

        }

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
           // getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exce unregisterReceiver", e.toString());

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Это еще хорошо что ваш код не приводит к вылетам приложения. После того как получаете данные - нужно информировать `RV` об изменениях, например вызвать `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Спасибо за совет а это надо в адаптере делать или уже в активити?

Comment: спасибо разобрался

Answer (score 2):

В общем проблема была в том что я упустил из виду notifyDataSetChanged(). После получения данных информируем адаптер и все работает

```
ChatsNotAnswered chatsid = new ChatsNotAnswered();
chatsid.setchatID(json.getInt("id"));
chatsid.setchatName(json.getString("name"));
chatsid.sethash(json.getString("hash"));
chatsid.setlastTime(json.getString("last_time"));
chated.add(chatsid);
rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```